# Determining what color from user input of the value of pixel

Tags: python

I think you have to split the string and then use if statements. Firstly, I am confused on how to split the string into groups of two. Any help much appreciated!

Example test programming problem. The colors of a pixel are represented using the strings with
the following formats '0xRRGGBB'. The R''s correspond to the amount of red, G's to green, and
B's to blue. If any of the values for either number are 00 then that means that none of that color 
is present and if they have any other value it means there is some of that color present. For 
example 0x100067 contains both red and blue, but no green while 0x458799 contains all three 
colors. Write a program that asks the user for a string representing the value of a pixel and tells 
the user what colors it contains.

Example:
Please enter the value of a pixel: 0x000099

This pixel contains the color blue

Example:
Please enter the value of a pixel: 0x104501

This pixel contains the color red

This pixel contains the color green

This pixel contains the color blue

Answer (score 1):

What you need to learn in how to use regular expressions and capture groups.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("0x(..)(..)(..)", "0x104501")
[('10', '45', '01')]
```

Which would essentially store the three matches into three capture groups.  Then use that to check if it's using r/g/b.